# Convert string based NaN's to numpy NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a part of it shown as below:

```
2016-12-27              NaN
2016-12-28              NaN
2016-12-29              NaN
2016-12-30              NaN
2016-12-31              NaN
Name: var_name, dtype: object
```

The column contains NaN as strings/objects. How can I convert it to a numpy nan instead. Best would be able to do so when I read in the csv file.

Comment: Can you just call `np.float64()` on that column?

Comment: Or set it to NaN with numpy.nan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the `converters` option in `read_csv`.  In this case, we are aiming to convert the column in question to numeric values and treat everything else as `numpy.nan` which includes string version of `'NaN'`

```
converter = lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, 'coerce')
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, converters={1: converter}, header=None)
df
```

[image]

```
df.dtypes

0     object
1    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df[var_name_replace] = df[var_name].replace('NaN', np.nan)
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'col':['NaN']*10})
```

You can use `.apply` to convert:

```
>>> new_df=df.apply(float, axis=1)
>>> type(new_df[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this when reading the csv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=['t', 'v'], dtype={'v':np.float64})
```

Check the docs of [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). There are some parameters is useful for your application:

- names
- dtype
- na_values

Hope this would be helpful.